# How to compare 2 different csv files and output the differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, compare

I have 2 CSVs which are New.csv and Old.csv that are have around 1K rows and 10 columns that has a structure like this:

[image]

If there is a longName (first column) in in the new.csv that is not in the old.csv, I would like that entire new.csv row to be appended to the changes.csv.

I started off by doing this but it does not work well at all:

```
def deltaFileMaker():
    with open('Old.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as t1, open('New.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as t2:
        fileone = t1.readlines()
        filetwo = t2.readlines()

    with open('changes.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile:
        for line in filetwo:
            if line not in fileone:
                outFile.write(line)



deltaFileMaker()
```

I also tried to use csv-diff but I could not find a way to convert its output to a csv file

**Update**

```
def deltaFileMaker():
    from csv_diff import load_csv, compare
    diff = compare(
        load_csv(open("old.csv",encoding="utf8"), key="longName"),
        load_csv(open("new.csv",encoding="utf8"), key="longName")
    )

        with open('changes.csv', 'w',encoding="utf8") as f:  
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, diff.keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(diff)


deltaFileMaker()
```

Doing this:
[image]

Comment: What was your code using csv-diff?

Comment: I just did the generic `csv-diff new.csv old.csv --key=id`, I couldn't figure out how to do anything else with it

Comment: Did you use `--key=id` or `--key=longName`?

Comment: Sorry, yes I used longName

Comment: If there is a way that I could convert the csv-diff to a csv file that would be perfect

Comment: If anyone could help me get the dictionary keys (longName, shortName, eventType, etc) to be columns and the values to be rows, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `csv-diff`? Their [website](https://pypi.org/project/csv-diff/) has an example that might be suitable:

```py
from csv_diff import load_csv, compare
diff = compare(
    load_csv(open("one.csv"), key="id"),
    load_csv(open("two.csv"), key="id")
)
```

This should return a `dict` object, which you can parse into a CSV file. To parse *that* dict into rows, this is an example. *Note: getting the changes to write correctly is difficult, but this is more of a proof-of-concept - modify as you wish*

```py
from csv_diff import load_csv, compare
from csv import DictWriter

# Get all the row headers across all the changes
headers = set({'change type'})
for key, vals in diff.items():
    for val in vals: # Multiple of the same difference 'type'
        headers = headers.union(set(val.keys()))

# Write changes to file
with open('changes.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    w = DictWriter(fh, headers)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, changes in diff.items():
        for val in changes: # Add each instance of this type of change
            val.update({'change type': key}) # Add 'change type' data
            w.writerow(val)
```

For the file `one.csv`:

```
id,     name, age
 1,     Cleo,   4
 2, Pancakes,   2
```

and `two.csv`:

```
id,   name, age
 1,   Cleo,   5
 3, Bailey,   1
4,  Elliot,  10
```

Running this produces:

```
change type,     name, id,               changes, age, key
      added,   Bailey,  3,                      ,   1,
      added,   Elliot,  4,                      ,  10,
    removed, Pancakes,  2,                      ,   2,
    changed,         ,   , "{'age': ['4', '5']}",    ,   1
```

So not great for all changes, but works really well for the added/removed rows.

Comment: I tried doing this but I must be doing something wrong. Please look at my update. If I could split it into 3 separate tables inside the changes.csv with added, changed, and removed that would be amazing.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have in your update?

Comment: Just added a screenshot, it's putting all the information in columns called added, removed, and changed.

Comment: I'll update my post with a way to do what you're asking :) @joe_sanders

Comment: Thank you Collin!

Comment: Thank you very much for making this example. It only shows one added row and removed row for me even though there are more than one. I'll try to make it so that it does it for all of them

Comment: That's my bad, I've never used `csv_diff` before, I will modify my example to permit >1 addition/removal @joe_sanders